# Eslint's Unable to resolve path to module when pointing to file and not a directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I have a React JS project with Typescript and I use Eslint for linting.
I have added path Aliases both to `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.config.json` which looks something like this

```
// webpack.config.json
components: path.resolve(__dirname, './../src/components/')
...
```

and

```
// tsconfig.json
"components/*": ["components/*"],
...
```

So, if I have a file like `src/components/Button/index.tsx` imported as `components/Button`, Eslint is quiet.

The problem comes when I have a file like `src/components/Loader.tsx` imported as `components/Loader`. Here the linter complains `Unable to resolve path to module 'components/Loader'`

**Please note:**

- The project compiles successfully.
- I do not want to suppress this warning using `"import/no-unresolved": 0` on my `eslintrc.json`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using components/Loader is the same as components/Loader/index.tsx but in your case, there is no such Loader folder that consists of the index.tsx file
To remove warning either create a folder structure with loader and index.tsx file or explicitly define you are accessing a file by components/Loader.tsx